# mv only if upload completed ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, mv

I'm looking to move files on a cron command, however I'm only wanting to move the completely uploaded files not the pending files as they'll be lots of files coming in. They'll be coming in sporadic intervals and quantities so unfortunately Aloiso Junior answer won't work.

Is there a way to use the mv command which ignores pending or active files ?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You mention moving only uploaded files (i.e. ones moved in a specific direction) , but you say there are lots coming in and out, implying both directions? Wouldn't it be better to let the scripts uploading/downloading files determine success and then do the moves? I don't understand.

Comment: Force of habbit, just files coming in, thanks for pointing that out question amended

Comment: So you are running an FTP server that is receiving files?

Comment: Correct, I have an automated pipeline of files coming in from various sources which uploads to the /home/ directory.

I want to then move them files to /var/www/html/ however only files which are completely uploaded as moving them before hand breaks the upload and you end up with partial files

Comment: I have thought of checking for exit codes, however I'm not sure how to append that to a move command, I was hoping for mv --exit-code=1 or something

Comment: Exit codes from where?

Comment: The normal way is to do a `PUT` on the FTP client to a file called `XYZ.inprogress` then do a `RENAME XYZ.inprogress XYZ` if the `PUT` is successful.

Answer (score 0):

My approach may help you,

First, add to end of upload queue a file, maybe a txt, it will represents the end of upload of all files.

you must have to directory a listener, to check presence or not of that .txt file.

**fswatch** can be handful

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/fswatch.7.html

If that .txt file have a list of all uploaded files, it can help you know all files you can safety move.

After move delete that .txt

Comment: Unfortunately as it'll be automated incoming files I won't be able to add text files on the trailing end of an upload.

What I could maybe do is only move files with an age over 1 hour for example ?

Comment: As legacy i'll keep answer to help someone whose have control about queue.

Comment: Create a cron, may help, but if there are new current upload files can you even perform this task?

Comment: I can use mv file.txt /directory/file.txt and if it's still uploading it will move partially completed file and break the upload